# Does it make sense to combine code coverage result for unit test and e2e test

Tags: end-to-end

In my company, there is a KPI about code coverage. We measure results by code coverage percentage.

So we combine code coverage result of unit test and end-to-end test together.
Does it make sense to do this?

Comment: That depends on what you do with the code coverage information. If it just to satisfy a useless KPI, then anything goes.

Comment: As @BartvanIngenSchenau stated, code coverage is a senseless KPI. The much more valuable information is *requirement coverage*. Unfortunately we have no tool to measure that. The only way to keep it high is TDD...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: That seems a bit fatalist.  Something is only senseless if it has no value at all, and I certainly don't believe that TDD is the only way to keep "requirement coverage" high.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle code coverage and requirement coverage are both useful and show different things imho. certainly for safety related stuff we use both

Comment: @jk. yes, code coverage has a value for estimating the *thrustworthyness* of the safety net the uniottests provide, but it does not make sense as a KPI. The reason is that if you define a minimum code coverage as a KPI you end up with bad unittest that do not verify desired behavior (as defined by the requirements) but just raise the code coverage. Developers later have a hard time to find out which UTs can safely be ignored and which are actual protecting existing desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does but with a few caveats:

Obviously you need to combine the metrics properly, not just add the coverage percentages. Usually there are tools to do this e.g. https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/merge-mojo.html

As with any metric you need to be careful how it is used. You probably don't want to look at *just* the merged value, the separate unit coverage and integration coverage is also potentially useful.

Unless you are required to meet a safety standard then aiming for 100% is probably pointless, the absolute number of the coverage may also be pointless but it may be useful to e.g. look at relative changes between builds.

Answer (score -3):

No, because you would get a result more than 100% which would be non nonsensical.

The correct way to combine them would be to check the percentage of code covered by Both e2e and unit tests. But again, this isn't a very useful number compared to a break down. eg:

- unit test coverage 60%
- integration test coverage 30%
- functional test coverage 10%

Comment: I combined coverage results many times but never had it over 100%. It was always "merge" kind when repeated coverage doesn't add up. Wonder what kind of tool or process one has to use to get senseless combined result over 100%

Comment: i wonder whether your 'merge' was AND or OR

Comment: I assume that one would combine these two metrics in a way that didn't create coverage over 100% (by adding the weighted averages, for example).

Comment: Jacoco has a tool specifically to do this properly, I'm sure other coverage tools also do similar things. obviously you can't just naively add the resulting percentages.